# Upload of JSON file using ForgeSDK, ObjectsAPI to Forge bucket failing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I'm trying to take a set of file stored in one bucket and copy them to another (one is transient and one is temporary - the files are to be stored for a longer period of time). I'm using the NodeJS ForgeSDK, using getObject to download the file, then uploadObject to put it in the second bucket. This seems to work fine for most of the files I'm moving, but fails when I try to use it on a JSON file.

I've tried converting the JSON both to a buffer and to a string before the uploadObject call, both fail giving a gateway timeout error.

Any suggestions on how to make this work? Thanks!

```
static copyObjectToBucket(oAuth2TwoLegged, bucketName, copyToBucketName, objectName, access, callback) {
    console.log(bucketName, copyToBucketName, objectName);
    ObjectsApi.getObject(bucketName, objectName, {}, oAuth2TwoLegged, oAuth2TwoLegged.getCredentials())
    .then((resp) => {
            var headers = resp.headers;
            var contentLength = headers['content-length'];
            var body = resp.body;
            if (objectName.includes('json')){
                body = JSON.stringify(body[0]);
            }

            ObjectsApi.uploadObject(copyToBucketName, objectName, contentLength, body, {}, oAuth2TwoLegged, oAuth2TwoLegged.getCredentials())
            .then(
                (res) =>{
                    console.log(res);
                    callback;
                }                  
            )
            .catch((err) =>{
                console.log(err);
                }
            );
        })        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are certain restrictions when it comes to uploading files to the Forge Data Management service, however JSON files should not be an issue. Please try uploading your JSON file some other way, for example:

- using an HTTP client such as [curl](https://curl.haxx.se) or [postman](https://www.postman.com)
- using another Node.js SDK: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-server-utils (disclaimer: it's my unofficial version of the Forge SDKs)
- using the [VSCode Forge extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petrbroz.vscode-forge-tools) (disclaimer: this one's mine, too, using the library mentioned above :))

If you can upload the JSON using one of these tools, it might be an issue in the SDK. In that case please report a bug in https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client.

Btw. I have just tried uploading a JSON file using the VSCode extension and found no issues.

Comment: Given that the JSON I'm copying is from a design automation job, and I have no problem uploading it via the OSS manager, it sounds like it's probably a bug. Thanks, Petr.

Comment: Hi Petr, I reported the bug as you suggested. I'm wondering if there's any progress on fixing it.

Comment: Hi Kate, I'm not an owner of that repo so I don't have any update but I'll try and ping the maintainer.